# How to plot smooth curve through the true data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, spline

I have tried a bunch of spline examples already posted for plotting smooth curves in python but those smoothed curves don't always cross through the true points. So far, I tried using
`make_interp_spline`, `interp1d`and also `BSpline`.

Is there any way (any spline option) I can plot a smooth curve that **must include/cross** through true data points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example with [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.random(5)
fun = interp1d(x=x, y=y, kind=2)
x2 = np.linspace(start=0, stop=4, num=1000)
y2 = fun(x2)

plt.plot(x2, y2, color='b')
plt.plot(x, y, ls='', marker='o', color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image: random spline interpolation]

You can easily verify that this interpolation includes the true data points:

```py
assert np.allclose(fun(x), y)
```