# Python - plotting interpolated curves: How to plot a trace curved line using Opencv/PIL/etc?

Tags: python, computer-vision, drawing

I am trying to track the head of golf club and draw its entire swing on the video. I am currently using OpenCV and YoloV5. Using Yolov5, I am able to detect the head of the golf club. On every frame, I have the golf club head and I am drawing a line. When I join the points as line, its coming straight instead of showing it the way swing has occurred. Is there a way in python (Currently using Opencv) to plot that swing ?

My end goal is something like: [the swing lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7c47.png)

But currently, I am getting only straight lines like this: [my current work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXc41.jpg)

Comment: How many frames are actually showing the swing? For a swing like you want it to have you need many frames a standard video probably does not provide.

Comment: [mre] is required. those pictures show the problem but they aren't debuggable.

Comment: @Claudio , Yeah, I think that. The actual swing happened in only 7-8 frames in my video, hence the lines are straight. But my main question is that I am not able to plot a parabola like curve through those points (Not even sure if its readily possible). Hence, wanted to have opinion of others.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Thanks for the suggestion as it's my first time posting something on stack.. but those are just straight lines across few points. Will try to post the code on gist and try updating the question.

Comment: so you're asking for interpolation? spline, bezier, something like that? to get usable answers, you need to know what to ask for. I'd strongly recommend that you revise the title of your question at the very least. -- if you're asking for interpolated curves, that'll just be a lie told to the viewer of the illustration. those sports analyses show accurate position/motion from high frame rate video (also very low motion blur). you need a high frame rate camera. 100-200 fps might be enough...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, by pointing my question mistakes, I am in much clear position now. Thank you for the same.  Yes, I am somewhat wanting to plot the interpolated curve.  But after reading your comment its getting clear that instead of plotting such things, I should move into better FPS video recording. My current video is 30 fps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949065/how-to-plot-smooth-curve-through-the-true-data-points-in-python-3 ( How to plot smooth curve through the true data points in Python 3? )